# why global variable executed only one time in nested loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

**Why global variable is executed only one time in nested while loop (inner)?**

```js
//not working as expected;
var i = 1;
var j = 1;
while(i<=3){
    console.log(i);
    i++;
    while(j<=3){
        console.log(j);
        j++;
    }
}

//working as expected;
var i = 1;
while(i<=3){
    console.log(i);
    i++;

    var j = 1;
    while(j<=3){
        console.log(j);
        j++;
    }
}
```

When I write the above code(**//not working as expected**) the inner while loop executes only 1st 3 times then it goes back to the top of outer while loop and executes it and doesn't come back to the inner while loop. But when I declare the variable and initialize it just before the while loop (**both inner and outer**) it executes fine. Why?

Comment: because in the first part J is   global

Comment: You should read about JS scoping first. Global variable can be changed and updated throughout your JS and values persists whichever is last changed.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `j` is not being reassigned and once it becomes > 3 inner loop is never executed.

```
//not working as expected;
var i = 1;
var j = 1;
while(i<=3){
    console.log(i);
    i++;
    while(j<=3){
        console.log(j);
        j++;
    }
}
```

In this code, during the first iteration of the outer loop, j increments from `1 to 3` when `i = 1`. When `i = 2`, j is already `4` and it is not being reassigned so condition `j <= 3` is false and the inner loop is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: j is not being reassigned back to 1 upon each iteration if it is global.

When the j variable is global, it does not get reset back to 1 for each loop.

```
outer loop output: i = 1
inner loop output: j = 1
inner loop output: j = 2
inner loop output: j = 3
outer loop output: i = 2
outer loop output: i = 3
```

When the j variable is within the first while loop it gets reset upon each iteration to output like so...

```
outer loop output: i = 1
inner loop output: j = 1
inner loop output: j = 2
inner loop output: j = 3

outer loop output: i = 2
inner loop output: j = 1
inner loop output: j = 2
inner loop output: j = 3

outer loop output: i = 3
inner loop output: j = 1
inner loop output: j = 2
inner loop output: j = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not changing the value back to 1
Try this:

```
var i = 1;
var j = 1;
while(i<=3){
 console.log(i);
 i++;
 while(j<=3){
    console.log(j);
    j++;
 }
 j = 1;
}
```